# Load, process and save larger-than-memory array using dask

Tags: numpy, out-of-memory, dask, numpy-memmap

I have a very large covariance matrix (480,000 x 480,000) stored on disk in a binary format. I want to compute a corresponding whitening matrix, for which I need to compute the SVD of the covariance matrix. I'm working on a very powerful system (40 cores, 360GB of RAM), but it still wasn't enough to do this computation in-memory. I'm trying to use a combination of numpy.memmap and dask to tackle this problem, since from what I understand, dask is able to read chunks of data, process them, and then even save results chunk-wise. However, I run into a MemoryError whenever I try to work with the full covariance matrix and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

This is a simplified version of the code I want to use:

```py
import numpy as np
import dask
import dask.array as da
from dask.distributed import LocalCluster, Client

client = Client(processes=False, n_workers=10, threads_per_worker=1, memory_limit="30GiB")

da_memmap = da.from_array(
    np.memmap("path_to_covariance_matrix.npy",
        mode="r",
        shape=(480000, 480000),
        dtype=np.float64
    ),
    chunks=(250, 480000)
)
```

`da_memmap` looks like this: [da_memmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFTcL.png)

```py
u, s, v = da.linalg.svd(da_memmap)

u_path = "/mnt/big_storage/test_u.npy"
s_path = "/mnt/big_storage/test_s.npy"
v_path = "/mnt/big_storage/test_v.npy"

u_map = np.memmap(u_path, mode="w+", dtype=np.float64, shape=da_memmap.shape)
s_map = np.memmap(s_path, mode="w+", dtype=np.float64, shape=da_memmap.shape[0])
v_map = np.memmap(v_path, mode="w+", dtype=np.float64, shape=da_memmap.shape)

da.store([u, s, v], [u_map, s_map, v_map], lock=False, compute=True)
```

Executing the above code using the full covariance matrix returns the following error.

```
2023-12-29 17:34:03,672 - distributed.protocol.pickle - ERROR - Failed to serialize <ToPickle: HighLevelGraph with 1 layers.
<dask.highlevelgraph.HighLevelGraph object at 0x786097501630>
 0. 132356258993664
>.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shash/miniconda3/envs/analysis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py", line 63, in dumps
    result = pickle.dumps(x, **dump_kwargs)
MemoryError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shash/miniconda3/envs/analysis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py", line 68, in dumps
    pickler.dump(x)
MemoryError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shash/miniconda3/envs/analysis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py", line 81, in dumps
    result = cloudpickle.dumps(x, **dump_kwargs)
  File "/home/shash/miniconda3/envs/analysis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 1479, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/home/shash/miniconda3/envs/analysis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 1245, in dump
    return super().dump(obj)
MemoryError
```

Running this code with a smaller covariance matrix, i.e. one that could theoretically fit completely into memory, does work. I played around with the chunk_size, but that doesn't help me. I'm now questioning whether dask is even capable of doing what I want it to do, so any clarifications in that direction would also be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the required 15TB of disk free?

Comment: I do. I have a 40TB disk connected to my system. Why would I need 15TB though?

Comment: oops 480000^2 * 8 / 10^12 = 2 TB

Comment: Even though you operate on memory mapped array, the resulting array is certainly not memory mapped and a temporary storage is certainly needed anyway for the SVD do be done (or similar operations). Linear algebra operations like an SVD are nearly never reimplemented by libraries : nearly all library use LAPACK (or more optimized variantes). In general, the temporary and output memory is allocated using a standard allocation so it is mapped on the physical memory or the swapping file/device which is certainly not 2 TiB wide.

Comment: A naive inefficient solution is to reserve like 4 TiB of swap on Linux (Windows certainly do not support such a big space and I am not sure this even work on Linux). A sane solution is not to compute such a big array and reimplement the operation so to avoid storing the whole matrices in memory. IDK if this is possible with an SVD since the operation is far from being trivial to do. Such an algorithm is called an out-of core algorithm. This is certainly a significant work (at least for someone not highly skilled).

Comment: An alternative solution is to perform the operation on multiple machines using distributed computing. This is what scientists tends to do for large scale operations : they use MPI and a distributed linear-algebra frameworks. If you are not familiar with this, this might not be simple to do either. Most of the time, there are workaround so to avoid generating huge matrices (possibly using advanced math or software tricks). For example, this is nearly never useful to write the covariance matrix in memory since it only contains very little information compared to its size.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://blog.dask.org/2020/05/13/large-svds